# How to create an array with counter?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am doing the following:

```
var myElement; 
var countElement = 0;
function wikiParsed(langPrefixElement) {
  countElement++;
  myElement[countElement] = {
```

But I get:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '1' of undefined

I am trying to achieve:

```
 myElement[1] 
 myElement[2] 
 myElement[3]
```

Also tried:

```
var myElement;
var countElement = 0;
function wikiParsed(langPrefixElement, countElement) {
  countElement++;
  myElement[countElement] = {
```

But I get:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'NaN' of undefined

Comment: Where is the rest of your code? At the moment with what you've provided we're unable to replicate the issue.

Comment: 1. Where are you defining `myElement` as an array? 2. Use `push()`

Comment: This seems like you have declared an associative array that you have not defined. Did you define the array?

Comment: sorry, just updated the question. p.s. Thanks for the quick down votes hey, not even the time to correct the question

Comment: @rob.m you have `var myArrayElement = [] `  but are using `myElement`

Comment: @George indeed, just updated

Comment: @rob.m you should check your question makes sense before you post it. Moaning about downvotes after posting a poor question is a little moot. Especially after *so* many poor questions.

Comment: `myElement` is undefined when you are trying to set `myElement[countElement]`.

Comment: @rob.m now it's not defined as an array. Please post your code as it is instead of changing it.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I agree, my apologies. had send it to quickly.

Comment: @George ok one of the issue from what you said is that i defined it as a var instead of an array, and that helped already yet not fully resolved but thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declare `myElement`, but it is just null.  In your function, trying to set an index of a null variable will do nothing. Additionally, you should increment after using the value, otherwise you miss out on the 0th element.

```js
var myElement = [];
var countElement = 0;

function wikiParsed(langPrefixElement) {
  myElement[countElement++] = countElement;
}
wikiParsed();
wikiParsed();
wikiParsed();
console.log(myElement);
```

Comment: If the issue remains you must have an issue elsewhere in your code as this works fine - as can be seen from the working snippet.

Comment: one quest: why are you using `myElement[countElement++] = countElement;` instead of `countElement++; myElement[countElement];` ?

Comment: You set `countElement` initially to `0`.  The first time you call the function `wikiParsed`, the `countElement` variable will be incremented to 1. Then, `myElement[1]` will be assigned a value.  This will end up with an array `[undefined, 1]...`

Comment: I realize your question does specify `myElement[1]`, which would be fine using your method, but since javascript has 0 indexed arrays, using the 0th element is the norm.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are attempting to use an Associative Array. Define it like so

```
var  myElement = {};

//Sample loop
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    myElement[i] = i;
}
```